# Different behavior of Mypy with generic class in Python 3.8 and 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, mypy

I have three classes:

```
class A: pass
class B: pass
class C: pass
```

And a generic class that deals with one of A, B or C.

```
from typing import cast, TypeVar, Generic, Union

T = TypeVar("T", A, B, C)

class K(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, x: T):
        self.x: T = x

    def f(self) -> T:
        return self.x
```

Then I have a function that returns instances of A or B:

```
def g() -> Union[A, B]:
    return A()
```

When initializing an instance of K with a result from g()

```
K(g())
```

Mypy 0.961 says this is ok in Python 3.8, but it complains in Python 3.10:

```
Value of type variable "T" of "K" cannot be "Union[A, B]"
```

Which should be the correct behavior?

Comment: can't reproduce ... i'm seeing the error for 3.8 and 3.10 ... see [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8)

Comment: (that's aside from the fact that i'm surprised - anything that's an `A | B` is also an `A` or a `B`)

Comment: I understand the reason for the error. If `K` receives an instance of `A`, the return type of `K.f()` is a specific type, as defined in `T`. But when it receives a union of `A` and `B`, the return type of `K.f()` is not determined before run time.
Including `A | B` in T solves the problem, but defeats the purpose of the generic class.

Comment: Thank you for pointing at the mypy playground. I have to check why my specific 3.8 setup doesn't flag the error.